# How do I write an if else statement in a makefile with the zsh shell?

Tags: shell, makefile, zsh

I am writing a makefile, and my shell is `zsh`. All is operating well until I hit an `if` statement. I've tried using the traditional [`ifeq` makefile statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html), but that doesn't appear to work when using `zsh`. So, I've tried just using `zsh` `if` statements, like the following:

```
if [[ "$(BUILD_ENV)" == "DEV" ]]; then
    @echo dev environment
else
    @echo not dev environment
fi
```

Every time I run it, I get the following error:

```
...
if [[ "DEV" == "DEV" ]]; then
zsh:1: parse error near `then'
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I've tried removing the semicolon (`;`), putting `then` on a new line (like in `bash` syntax), but to no avail.

**How can I properly perform an `if else` statement in a makefile, using `zsh` as the shell?**

Comment: Are you trying to put this conditional inside a rule?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete `makefile` that shows the context in which `zsh` syntax is being used.

Answer (score 0):

It's irrelevant what shell you use (consider the insanity if make always used the shell of the user who invoked it... no makefile could ever be portable between two people!)

`make` *always* uses `/bin/sh`.  If you want to use some different shell you must explicitly set it in your makefile by adding:

```
SHELL := /bin/zsh
```

However, I don't recommend this because not every system will have zsh installed.

You should simply write your recipes to use portable POSIX syntax rather than using zsh extensions.  In this case, that means using `[`..`]` instead of `[[`...`]]` and using `=` for equality instead of `==`.

Also, remember that each logical line of a makefile is invoked in a separate shell so if you want to write an if-statement you have to use backslashes to ensure all the physical lines are combined into a single logical line:

```
mytarget:
        @if [ "$(BUILD_ENV)" = "DEV" ]; then \
            echo dev environment; \
        else \
            echo not dev environment; \
        fi
```

Comment: Why does the error say `zsh:1:...` if `/bin/sh` is in use? Clearly, they *are already* jumping through the hoops necessary to have their copy of `make` use zsh.